# AngularJS tutorial "A module is created.."

Tags: angularjs

In the tutorial:

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_modules.asp

"A module is created by using the AngularJS function angular.module."

However, the module is already existent in the div tag defined before

```
<div ng-app="myApp">...</div>
```

Then what is the significance of the quoted statement above?

Danke / Dhonnobad (I hope it doesn't get deleted :) )

Comment: By creating angular module, you fill that div and replace ...

Comment: The HTML doesn't define the angularJS module, it's just a way of using it within the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`angular.module` in fact creates module - your app configuration, so when angular process html and found `ng-app` directive - it will instantiate your app using that configuration.

In terms of i.e. Java you can say `angular.module` creates Class, 
when `<div ng-app="myApp">` creates instance.

Answer (score 1):

The module is a container for the application controllers and directives, in general.

Incase you mention in index.html as,
`<div ng-app="myapp"> ..</div>` 
And you maintain a separate javascript file for controller codes and directive codes, to avoid messing up in html file in between script tags, consider in index.js, You give it as

```
var app=angular.module("myapp",[])
```

And then you can add controllers like ,

```
app.controller("mycontroller",function($scope){
        //javascript code
     });
```

This is how controller functions act upon module specified. Hope this suffice.